# Homographs: how to deal with them?

Tags: furigana, okurigana

For example:

> - 一日{いちにち} = one day (duration);
> - 一日{ついたち} = first day of the month.

First of all, are the meanings correct? Because I found contradicting answers.
I suspect the meanings are overlapping in some cases?

Then, after a quick search, I found out that *okurigana* is efficient to disambiguate them. Didn't the author mean *furigana* instead? Maybe I didn't grasp something here.

Lastly, what are the most important (to know)/most frequent homographic Kanji out there?

Comment: I didn't find a tag with "homographic-kanji", I'll create a tag wiki for that.

Comment: "duration" would be 一日中

Comment: Can 一日 also be duration? Maybe a less precise and more general term than 一日中?

Comment: Actually 一日中 means throughout the day, and 一日 can be used as a durational count.

Comment: @Flaw Thanks, yeah I noticed that too when I looked it up. I suppose your comment means the two meanings are quite different.

Comment: I think that the tag name [homographic-kanji] should be changed to [homographs].  I posted this on [meta](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/535/tag-name-homographic-kanji-%e2%86%92-homographs), so if you or anyone has a comment on this, please post there instead of here.

Comment: Note that `ついたち` has its own special kanji that can be used:  `朔【ついたち】` or `朔日【ついたち】`.  Although I don't know how (un)commonly they may be used.  As for the disambiguation, I think the context of where they appear should be enough.

Comment: @Alenanno You are right. The author probably mistook furigana and okurigana. Maybe the author is a non-native. If okurigana is different, then there wont be an issue of ambiguity. For example, `切ない` reads 'せつない`, and `切れない` reads 'きれない'.

Comment: Can someone please explain the close vote? It's not helpful to vote to close a question that actually shows a real problem, especially without giving an explanation for that close vote. In this case then, about close-vote reason that was "NARQ", I'd like to ask who voted: please, stand up and explain why my question would be "*ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical*" and why it can't be "*reasonably answered in its current form.*" Thank you

Comment: @Alenanno: I voted NARQ. You'll notice I tried to answer (even before voting).  Trying to answer convinced me the question, as is, wasn't proper.
And it's also one single vote; you don't have to take that badly. As far as I know, the question is still open, as the community decided…

Comment: @Axioplase Thanks for responding. I was not really taking it badly, I was mostly wondering why there was no explanation about it (but I was a bit surprised too, honestly, because it didn't seem like a "NARQ" question). Anyway, if you tell me what was not proper in your opinion, I'd appreciate it! Thanks. P.S. Just to be clear, I have no problem with you! :)

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, are the meanings correct?

Yes, you are right.

> Then, after a quick search, I found out that okurigana is efficient to disambiguate them. Didn't the author mean furigana instead?

Yes, he's wrong.

> Lastly, what are the most important (to know)/most frequent homographic Kanji out there?

Err, all the X中, where 中 is read ちゅう or じゅう.
And also

> 今日 -- こんにち(today, nowadays, or in "こんにちは")/きょう(today),
>   明日 -- あす/あした/みょうにち、
>   昨日 -- さくじつ/きのう
>   今年 -- こんねん/ことし…

Basically, the "on.yomi" is more formal than the other readings.

I have no idea how to rank anything (which I can't even remember) by importance…
I'd like to say that there aren't that many, and that answering would be vain, barely a useful information (if you ignore proper nouns…)

Comment: Your answer is good enough, but about the examples... I was not really requiring a "rank" type of list... Just a small list, or some examples, about some expressions that have the same issues. Something on the lines of "These are the most known exceptions" for grammar. :) And 今日 is also read こんにち? I thought it only was きょう...

Comment: Yes, "こんにち" means "nowadays".

Comment: Great! So きょう means "today" and こんにち means "nowadays"? If you organize that part of the answer to highlight these differences, it'd be wonderful! I was looking for something like that. :)